# Как работает возврат по значению?

Tags: c++

```
class Dollars {
private:
    int dollars;
public:
    Dollars(int dol) : dollars(dol) {}

    friend Dollars get(const Dollars&, const Dollars&);
};

Dollars get(const Dollars& dol, const Dollars& dd) {
    return dol.dollars + dd.dollars;
}
```

В строчке `return dol.dollars + dd.dollars;` создается анонимный объект(**и уничтожается в этой строчке??**) и создается копия на основе анонимного объекта, которая в свою очередь возвращается в caller, у которой область видимости в пределах выражения?

А если сделать так:

`return Dollars(dol.dollars + dd.dollars);` Здесь мы явно создаем анонимный объект и уже на основе анонимного объекта создается копия?

Comment: В современном С++ тут создается только один объект, который и возвращается.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/666330/